# BitBlt | StretchBlt - Access is denied when the user is not logged in to Windows

Tags: python, winapi

I have a python program that uses simple Windows GDI functions like BitBlt and StretchBlt which runs at computer startup but it starts before the user has logged in at the logon screen and that results in an `[Error 5] Access is denied`. Is there a way to see when the user has logged in to Windows and then start the program?

Comment: How are you starting the program before a user has logged in? Are you using a background service, a Registry `Run` key, a Start Menu `Startup` group, or something else?

Comment: It uses the Userinit key in`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` to run

Comment: Userinit is undocumented? You should use something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong Registry key.  You can't run a **GUI** program from the `Winlogon` key, since WinLogon runs outside of any user session.

Use a [`Run` key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) instead, eg: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`:

> Use `Run` or `RunOnce` registry keys to make a program run **when a user logs on**.

Comment: But is there a way to detect the user session and then run the program from Winlogon key?

Comment: There is no user session yet when Winlogon first starts running. Code that needs to run before a user logs in should be implemented in a background service run by the SCM, not in a GUI app run by Winlogon. But GDI is tied to desktops of user sessions (Winlogon runs in its own secure desktop), so it doesn't really make sense to manipulate user GDI objects from code run by Winlogon anyway. so what are you really trying to accomplish in the first place? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: The program I'm making isn't just GDI and it runs by Winlogon because it needs to run immediately after the computer starts and `Run` key in registry takes a little bit of time to start the program after logon (like 5-7 seconds). Also I'm asking if there is a way to make my program wait until the user session after logon (the user logs in to Windows) and then start the GDI functions.

Comment: @len This has XY Problem written all over it. If you need a solution to your actual problem, you need to ask about your *problem* rather than what you believe to be the solution. As far as the question you asked goes, this proposed answer addresses it (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: @Lennox "*The program I'm making isn't just GDI*" - sounds like you need to separate your code logic in a more meaningful manner. Business logic should be separate from UI logic. "*it needs to run immediately after the computer starts*" - a background service can accomplish that, even before Winlogin runs. "*`Run` key in registry takes a little bit of time to start the program after logon (like 5-7 seconds)*" - because that is when it is safe for UI programs to start interacting with the user session...

Comment: @Lennox ... "*I'm asking if there is a way to make my program wait until the user session after logon (the user logs in to Windows) and then start the GDI functions*" - the `Run` key is the correct way to handle that. However, a background service can get `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` events for logins/logout. So, you still shouldn't be relying on the `Winlogin` key.